# What is a gold steering wheel in multi-player?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

When playing Mario Kart Wii online there seem to be 3 controller categories displayed next to player names;

- none - normal wii controller/controller + nunchuck.
- white steering wheel - being hardcore and using the steering wheel.
- gold steering wheel - ???.

**What is the gold steering wheel and what does it signify?**

Comment: At a guess I'd say using the nunchuk, as that'd be the third option?

Comment: that is the first option, I will update the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Various](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/942008-mario-kart-wii/faqs/60453) [FAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/942008-mario-kart-wii/faqs/52407) claim that you get the Gold Wheel display for "playing with the wheel a lot", but give no more detailed information.

However, the outcome of [this discussion](http://uk.gamespot.com/mario-kart-wii/forum/unlocking-golden-wheel-42899835/) as well as [this thread](http://www.mariokartwii.com/f7/golden-wheel-how-question-10382-2.html) indicate that the following critera need to be met:

- You have to have raced at least 100 races.
- You need to have used Wii Wheel as your controller more than 50% of the time.

That last link is on the official Mario Kart Wii forums and cites the official game guide, so it seems pretty trustworthy.

Comment: And to think, I always thought the Golden Wheel simply symbolized the leader of the room or something similar :P. Shows how observant and understanding I am of the little things, eh? :P

Comment: I've saw one answer mentioning "from the official Mario Kart Wii guide", but I guess that one is only available in book version (or perhaps is delivered along with the CD?) so it could be hard to obtain.

Comment: @TomWijsman - A quick search with that info turned up an answer from the official game forums referencing the official guide, which I think is the best source we have at present. Answer updated - thank you! :)

Comment: @raveturned: Yeah, but it could be a guide he found somewhere on a domain name that contains the words "mario", "kart" and/or "wii". So I really don't trust it 100%, unless it carries the Nintendo brand or some definitive conclusion that it is more than just speculation...

Comment: I suppose so. I'd assumed they meant [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Mario-Kart-Wii-Official-Guides/dp/0761559701) - official Prima game guide with what looks like an official Nintendo seal on the bottom right of the cover - but since the citation is vague perhaps they didn't. I guess a page reference and a direct quote from that guide would be the best we could get.

Answer (score 0):

The "golden wheel", as you put it, is an icon displayed during multiplayer mode if you have used the wii wheel frequently. You don't just get the golden wheel by playing with the wii wheel for a day or two, you need to have used it atleast half the time you race. To get the icon you also need to have raced at least 100 times using the wheel. If you see a golden wheel with stars next to it, it means that the player has won many rounds using the wii wheel.